# ArcGIS Silverlight Web Mapping Application has two logins

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-silverlight-api, silverlight, authentication

I am trying to implement a Silverlight Web Mapping application with ArcGIS server and I'm trying to use the Token authentication with active directory as the user/roles store.

I have the service running so that I can successfully obtain tokens but when I try to initialize a map service the ArcGIS server challenges me again to authenticate with widows even though I have successfully created a token.

The IIS is set for windows authentication but in any other configuration (Anonymous, Impersonate) the map service never loads.

```
        //Import  Base Data Map Service
        ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer BaseMap = new ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer();
        BaseMap.Url = DataSourceStrings.ProductionServer + DataSourceStrings.I_GeneralWesternCanadaURL;
        BaseMap.Token = Token; // This is a valid token
        BaseMap.ID = "BaseMap";
        BaseMap.Visible = true;
        //BaseMap.ImageFormat = ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer.RestImageFormat.PNG32;
        BaseMap.Refresh();
        BaseMap.InitializationFailed += ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer_InitializationFailed;
        BaseMap.Initialized += ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer_Initialized;
        Map.Layers.Insert(0, BaseMap);
```

Solution...?
So I managed to fix this by setting the Server.dat file to disable security but the services still require a token in their web.config files. Seems Arcgis server like to handle the windows authentication but the design was to handle the authentication in silverlight using a wcf service. I've tested this and everything seems to work the way i want it too. Kinda of a hack way of doing it but everything works right.

Comment: Post your code where it references the REST service in your Silverlight app.